# LINQ: Finding an item in a List which contains List of items

Tags: linq, list, find, windows-store-apps

guys!

I have a small issue with **LINQ** (Im total beginer in this topic). Maybe it is some desing mistake, but let you decide it.
I'm coding a *Windows Store App*, which is kind a calendar. It has a *Day* object. Because of the semantic zoom (and some groupping hack), I put this Day into a wrapper class, named as *Month*.

After loading all data, and after getting the current data, I want to extract from this structure the current Day object.
Here is the important code:

```
public class Day
{
    public int nr { get; set; }
    ...
}
public class Month
{ 
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public List<Day> Days{get;set;}
}
```

Later I have this:

```
List<Month> Months;
```

It is correctly filled with lists of days. Now comes the tricky part:

```
Day Today = Months.Find( ??? )
```

I had some idea, but none of them was statisfying...

So, the question is:

**How can I select an item from a multiple list hierarchy in LINQ?**

```
(List<List<Day>>, and one condition must met in each list (Day.nr and Month.nr))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an Enum for every month:

```
public enum NamesOfMonths
{
    January = 1,
    February = 2,
    // so on and so forth
}
```

Now, you can use it to find the correct Month, and eventually the correct Day.

```
var dayToday = DateTime.Now.Day;
var monthToday = DateTime.Now.Month;

Day Today = Months.Find(m => m.Title.Equals(((NamesOfMonths)monthToday).ToString()))
    .Days.Where(d => d.Nr == dayToday).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `SelectMany`:

```
var days = months.SelectMany(m => m.Days); // Gets all the days in those months
var today = days.Where(d => /* some condition goes here */);
```

Comment: Not exactly. Im looking for only one day. And the day's nr, is not an universal id, so each month has 1., 2., etc days. But if you could specify how to select only one month in the first row, you solved my problem. :)

Comment: And also, the type of `var today` is actualy and IEnum.